# How can i make my void public to use everywhere

Tags: c#, forms, datetime, void, public

```
public void Tarih()
{
     var baslangicTarih = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-20).Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0));
     DateTime bitisTarih = DateTime.Now.Date.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0));
     TimeSpan Sonuc = bitisTarih - baslangicTarih;
}
```

But when i try to use "baslangicTarih" on another void like this:

```
Btn1_Click
    if (result.StartDate!= null)
    {
        baslangicTarih = result.StartDate;
        bitisTarih = result.EndDate;
    }
```

It says this "CS0103  C# The name does not exist in the current context".

How can i use `baslangicTarih` and `bitisTarih` on another void (without adding class)?

Answer (score 1):

Because you have defined those variables in that method scope and they won't be accessible outside that method. What you need is class level fields for this. For example:

```
public class MyClass
{
   // now variables are at class level scope
   // all methods can access them now
   DateTime baslangicTarih;
   DateTime bitisTarih;

  public void MethodA()
  {
     baslangicTarih = DateTime.Now;
     bitisTarih = DateTime.Now;

  }

  public void MethodB()
  {
     baslangicTarih = DateTime.Now;
     bitisTarih = DateTime.Now;
  } 
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this.

Comment: you need to read the basics of c# then try something practical

Comment: please explain not working, this does not help solving your problem

Comment: This is just not working, errors are gone but code is not working.

Comment: please revise your question or better ask new question as now this is a new problem

Answer (score 0):

The variables are available in the context method. To access everywhere, declare them in class

```
public class MyClass
{
     public DateTime baslangicTarih ;
     public DateTime bitisTarih;

     public void MyMethod()
     {

         if (result.StartDate!= null)
         {
             this.baslangicTarih = result.StartDate;
             this.bitisTarih = result.EndDate;
         }
```

Comment: I am using these 2 everywhere in the code. So I don't want to type "DateTime baslangicTarih ;
DateTime bitisTarih;" everytime i use. I want to make a public datetimes and use it everywhere.